# Decoding is not constant with PySerial

Tags: python-3.x, serial-port, pyserial, raspberry-pi4

I'm trying to automate the login of a serial connection. Right now I'm doing baby steps with PySerial and the decoded output was not constant with what to decode. The network is like this:

```
PC (Windows 10) -> Switch -> Router -> Switch -> Raspberry Pi 4 -> Router
```

I connect to the Raspberry Pi 4 via SSH and from there I connect with an USB to RS-232 adapter to the Router (Lancom-1926VAG-5G).

The serial connection works I already tried that with PuTTY, Screen and Minicom. The baudrate is ambigous but can be between from 9600 to 115200.
Right now this is my test code for the serial connection:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import serial
import time

ser = serial.Serial(port='/dev/ttyUSB0', baudrate=57600, parity="N", stopbits=1, bytesize=8, timeout=3, rtscts=True)

ser.reset_input_buffer()
ser.reset_output_buffer()

print(ser.isOpen())

i = 0
while i<=15:
    time.sleep(0.1)
    ser.write(''.encode('utf-8') + b'\n')
    i = i+1

print(ser.inWaiting())

input_data = ser.read(1024).decode('utf-8', errors='replace').strip()
print(input_data)
```

A normal connection with PuTTY looks like this:

```
b▒▒▒ĥ▒▒$▒▒d▒
Outband-115200 Bit/s OK

#
| LANCOM 1926VAG-5G
| Ver. 10.72.0092SU2 / 15.02.2023
| SN.  
| Copyright (c) LANCOM Systems

Connection No.: 001 (Outband-115200 Bps)

Password:
Login Error



Goodbye
```

But when I try the code it looks like this:

```
True
391
G�ɰhj��hL@Е��
Outband-57600 Bit/s OKr~Iy�b܁�nĒb���
� b�߿�<�lb����
�����p���������������p�
����

�CBRTb���Ą��$��d�G�ɰ)j��hL@Е��
Outband-57600 Bit/s OK~�y�b܁�nĒb���
� b�߿�<�$b���������p���������������p�
����
�CBRT���Ą��$��d�G�ɰ(j��hL@Е��
Outband-57600 Bit/s OKr~Yy�b܁�nĒb�
��
� b�O���lb�
�����
���p������������`��p�����
```

Again but this time with the same baudrate as in the PuTTY output:

```
True
668
Outband-115200 Bit/s OKr~�y�b܁�nĒb��
�
� b�߿�<�lb怘���f?`?<<��`<�f~x��3���?�������������p��������������p������������������������������������������b���ĥ��$��d�
Outband-115200 Bit/s OKr~�y�b܁�nĒb��
�
� b�߿�<�lb怘���f?`?<<��`<�f~x��3���?�������������p��������������p������������������������������������������b���ĥ��$��d�
Outband-115200 Bit/s OKr~�y�b܁�nĒb��
�
� b�߿�<�lb怘���f?`?<<��`<�f~x��3���?�������������p��������������p������������������������������������������
```

Why is the message "Outband-57600 Bit/s OK" getting decoded but nothing after? (Edit: The router keeps negotiating the baudrate with the code)

Edit:
After tracing the outband of the router I noticed something.
The gibberish I kept getting was the negotiation of the baudrate with the router.

Comment: "*The baudrate is ambigous ...*" -- What? Tell us facts rather than your interpretation disguised as fact. "*A normal connection with PuTTY looks like this: ...*" -- What baudrate is PuTTY configured with? What does your code produce with the same baudrate that PuTTY is using, presumably 115200? "*But when I try the code ...*" -- Why does your code use a baudrate that is apparently different from what produces readable results that you have seen??? "*Why is the message "Outband-57600 Bit/s OK" getting decoded ...?*" -- Probably because you're using the incorrect baudrate for the login.

Comment: @sawdust Every baudrate between 115200 and 9600 works for the router (115200, 57600. 38400 28800, 19200, 14400, 9600). If you had read the question you would have seen that I wrote that. Should I post every output from every baudrate of the code?

Comment: The output changes slightly when the baudrate is changed. But the gibberish of every baudrate is constant. (Not that the gibberish stays the same for every baudrate but each baudrate has specific gibberish)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I applied LANtrace to the outband connection. I found that the router waited for a specific handshake, so the negotiation always fails. After tracing a connection with PuTTY, I saw the connection between the two. After I changed the code to send carriage return or 0x0D

```
ser.write(b'\r')
```

the negotiation was successful. If the router detects the 0x0D the router will then lock the baudrate and then send its login prompt.
It atleast works now and I hope it helps somebody out there.